# Django: How to update one field at a time on a form?

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms

I've been trying to find a solution online but I haven't found any that works, I was hoping you guys could help me out with this as I've been in this situation for a two days now. My problem is whenever I tried to update one of the fields of my User an error pops up saying that it is required to update the other fields too. I've tried putting `blank=True` on one of the fields of my User model so that the required thing will turn to False, but when I click update on the front end those fields that I haven't changed turn to blank. All I want is to let the user be able to update one field if he or she wants too without the need to update the other fields.. just like on the admin site, you can freely update one field of a user and it would not throw you an error. Could someone help me out with this?

this is my view

```
class ProfileUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin,UpdateView):
    model = User
    form_class = UserUpdateForm
    template_name = 'accounts/profile_update.html'

def get_object(self, *args, **kwargs):
    return User.objects.get(username=self.kwargs.get('username'))

def get_success_url(self):
    self.object = self.get_object()
    return reverse_lazy('accounts:profile_update', self.request.user.username)
```

this is my form

```
class UserUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'phone_number', 'current_address', 'image']
```

I tried this

My view

```
class ProfileUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin,UpdateView):
    model = User
    form_class = UserUpdateForm
    template_name = 'accounts/profile_update.html'

def get_object(self, *args, **kwargs):
    return User.objects.get(username=self.kwargs.get('username'))

def get_success_url(self):
    self.object = self.get_object()
    return reverse_lazy('accounts:profile_update', self.request.user.username)

#I added this
def get_form_kwargs(self):
    form = super().get_form_kwargs()
    form['user'] = self.request.user
    return form
```

My form

```
class UserUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    #I added this
    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = user
        super(UserUpdateForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields['first_name'].initial = user.first_name
        self.fields['last_name'].initial = user.last_name
        self.fields['email'].initial = user.email
        self.fields['phone_number'].initial = user.phone_number
        self.fields['current_address'].initial = user.current_address
        self.fields['image'].initial = user.image

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'phone_number', 'current_address', 'image']
```

I also tried `get_initial` on my updateview

```
def get_initial(self):
    initial = super().get_initial()

    initial['first_name'] = self.request.user.first_name
    initial['last_name'] = self.request.user.last_name
    initial['email'] = self.request.user.email
    initial['phone_number'] = self.request.user.phone_number
    initial['current_address'] = self.request.user.current_address
    initial['image'] = self.request.user.image

    return initial
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried populating the form you wish to update with existing data? I think that should solve the blank problem.

In the
**ProfileUpdateView class**

you should try querying the data and putting it in a context dictionary, then  populate the

```
form_class = UserUpdateForm()
```

It should look something like

```
if request.method == "POST":
    form_class = UserUpdateForm(request.POST, instance='context dictionary key')
```

This will auto fill all fields with the first added data

Then to set only one field to be visible just go to the forms.py file

```
set fields = '__all__'
```

Then use exclude to hide all other fields, like this

```
exclude = ['image', 'phone_number', 'current_address']
```

It's as simple as that. Any field you add to exclude will not show up and it's content will be intact. If you need further assistants email me.